# How do I make a custom multilayered background repeat past initial viewport in scss?

Tags: html, sass, scroll, jquery-animate

*Yes, I already looked at all the suggested answers. No, none of them work*

So I've created an animated background of stars that I want to make repeat for as far down as you scroll on my website. However, when you scroll past the initial viewport, the background cuts off.[image]

The following is my (relevant) SCSS code. Does anyone know what I would need to change?

```scss
.stars-container {
    background: black repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;

    @mixin stars-child($time, $opacity) {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        animation: slide $time linear infinite;
        opacity: $opacity;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    .stars1 {
        @include stars-child(10s, 100%);
        background: url(/images/stars/1.png) repeat center; 
    }
    .stars2 {
        @include stars-child(20s, 95%);
        background: url(/images/stars/2.png) repeat center; 
    }
    .stars3 {
        @include stars-child(30s, 90%);
        background: url(/images/stars/3.png) repeat center; 
    }
    .stars4 {
        @include stars-child(40s, 85%);
        background: url(/images/stars/4.png) repeat center; 
    }
    .stars5 {
        @include stars-child(50s, 80%);
        background: url(/images/stars/5.png) repeat center; 
    }
    .stars6 {
        @include stars-child(60s, 75%);
        background: url(/images/stars/6.png) repeat center; 
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        from {background-position: 0px;}
        to {background-position: 900px;}
    }
}
```

And this is the very minimal bit of HTML that I used to implement this background

```html
    <div class="stars-container">
        <div class="stars1"></div>
        <div class="stars2"></div>
        <div class="stars3"></div>
        <div class="stars4"></div>
        <div class="stars5"></div>
        <div class="stars6"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not a backgorund, this is a div. If you want your div to be fixed, you should position it accordingly: `.stars-container {position: fixed;}`. You might need to add `right: 0; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

***Instead of adding an image behind each item, why not just put an image in the background of the container?***

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stars-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-animation: bg-stars 60s linear 0s Infinite alternate both;
    animation: bg-stars 60s linear 0s Infinite alternate both;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520034475321-cbe63696469a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80);
    background-size: 200%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: gold;
}
.stars-container > div {
    flex: 1 1 33.33333%;
    color: white;
    padding-block: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-stars {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 200% 0;
    }
}

@keyframes bg-stars {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 200% 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="stars-container">
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```